# Cant get chrome.tabs.executeScripts to work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to modify an existing chrome extention.

What i want is a chrome extention where i populate a popup window full of urls and then when i click OK each url opens up in a new tab 1 at a time,  certain data on that tab is then copied somewhere, the tab closes and the next url in the list is called and so on untill the list is complete.  the extention finally outputs all the copied data from all the tabs into a CSV file (which i can then manipulate into Excel.

I have looked everywhere but so far i have only got as far as to open the tabs up HOWEVER they all open at the same time.  this i sas far as i have got.

I have tried using chrome.tabs.execute script and that seems to block the loop,

Any ideas?

EDIT - HERE IS THE FULL CODE

Many Thanks

```
function loadSites(e) {
var urlschemes = ['http', 'https', 'file', 'view-source'];
var urls = document.getElementById('urls')
    .value.split('\n');
var lazyloading = document.getElementsByName('lazyloading')[0].checked;
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    theurl = urls[i].trim();
    if (theurl != '') {
        if (urlschemes.indexOf(theurl.split(':')[0]) == -1) {
            theurl = 'http://' + theurl;
        }
        if (lazyloading && theurl.split(':')[0] != 'view-source' && theurl.split(':')[0] != 'file') {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: chrome.extension.getURL('lazyloading.html#') + theurl,
                selected: false
            });
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: theurl,
                selected: true, 
                activ
                function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "contentscript.js" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Move `}` from the last `})` to right after `selected: true,`. See the documentation.

Comment: I have uploaded the full code which is what i should have done in the first place,  BTW,   i am new at Javascript

Comment: In addition to the comment above, make sure you're using devtools. Right-click the popup then click inspect. You'll see errors in its console panel about invalid syntax in your code.